# Open terminal and execute command with arguments in command line mac

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, arguments

I am currently using :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -a Terminal" + directory + " " + argument);
```

My argument happens to also be a directory.

My problem is that it will open argument instead of considering it an argument of directory. The outcome will be the same as running the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -a Terminal" + directory)
```

and

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -a Terminal" + argument)
```

Instead of typing directly in a terminal :

```
$/Users/xxxxx/RestOfPath /Users/xxxxx/argument
```

Is there a solution which would look like this without parenthesis?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -a Terminal (" + directory + " " + argument+ ")");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try escaping the space

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -a Terminal" + directory + "\\ " + argument);
```

Comment: This didn't work, nothing opened as the command was not recognized.